# What is the MySQL database url format to establish connection in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What is the database url format for MySQL you pass to `establish_connection` method?

```
class ModelBase < ApplicationRecord
  establish_connection "mysql database url"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Format: `adapter://username:password@host/database_name`

Example: `mysql2://username:password@localhost/database_name`